# vim coloring specific text

Tags: vim, colors

I wonder (and so far I didn't find an answer on google, but maybe it was in front of me and I got confused by the quantity of informations about relatives questions) if I can specify a style (ie a color) to a specific part of text in vim ?

for exemple, here if i write ** text ** the text shows up in bold font : **text**

or maybe I can select some words, and then apply a color to them ?

the purpose is to make easier to read files that are note code files

thx !

Comment: :help syntax it's a good starting point to write your own syntax colouring vimscript.

Comment: ok I'll check that during the week-end I hope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
set concealcursor=n                                                             
set conceallevel=3                                                              
hi Asterisks NONE
hi AsteriskBold  cterm=bold gui=bold
syn match Asterisks contained "**" conceal                                      
syn match AsteriskBold "\\\@<!\*\*[^"*|]\+\*\*" contains=Asterisks
```

The last four lines are very similar to those defined in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/help.vim` to hide bars (`|`). Instead here we want to conceal double asterisks (`**`).

For first two lines see `:help concealcursor` and `:help conceallevel`. The next two lines define the highlighting groups `Asteriks` and `AsteriskBold`. The two final lines define the syntax matching patterns (see `:help pattern` and `:help contains`).

Comment: ho great ! is it possible to explain more the action of each lines ?
should i put that in my .vimrc ?

Comment: I added some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

thx BigMike & Sergio !

@Sergio so, I've puted your lines in my vimrc file, thx it helped a lot :)
I add comments to save times for other beginners like me :

-> **conceal** means hidden characters, it's used here to hide the * *, while the other commands transform what's between any pair of * *

-> the **concealcursor=n** means the characters are hidden in normal mode, but you see them in visual mode or insertion mode (it could be equal to 'v' or 'i' or multiple values like 'nv' to hide characters in both normal and visual mode)

-> the **conceallevel=3** means that characters will be complerely hidden (set to '0' means it's not hidden, and '1' and '2' is about replacing them by something else)

-> **hi** and **syn** will be used to transform the texte surrounded by '* *'

-> **hi** means highlights, it specifies how choosen text will appears, so it's set to **NONE** for Asterisks, which means it will not be transformed (I'm not sure it's necessary since it will be hidden)

-> the selection **AsteriskBold** is made bold by **cterm=bold**. In my shell **gui=bold** do nothing so I erased it, and I added **ctermfg=Green** BEFORE **cterm=bold** to color the text in green in addition of making it bold (before : because it specified in ':help hi' to place it before to avoid problems that I don't understand)

-> **syn match Asterisks "* *" conceal** I think this line define what the variable Asterisks stand for, and that it should be concealed (hidden)

-> **syn match AsteriskBold `\\\@<!\*\*[^"*|]\+\*\*` contains=Asterisks** this line define what text match for the name AsteriskBold with a regex, that I don't totaly understand (I erased the beginning **`\\\@<!`** because I don't know what it does and it works great without it so far, and i changed the set of character by just `[^*]` because I want the pattern to match even when there is a " or a |), I also do not understand why the + works either with the backslash before or not. and the end 'contains=Asterisks' is necessary but I don't get the logic of this formulation... if we don't put it, or if we didn't defined what Asterisks was in the previous line, the conceal action doesn't work, but the highlight does...

Finally I still have an issue : sometime I want to transform a * character, and I can't find how to transform the regex for that purpose ?? I mean

```
*****
```

do not show a bold green *, but instead it shows nothing

here are my lines :

```
set concealcursor=n                                                             
set conceallevel=3                                                              
hi AsteriskBold  ctermfg=Green cterm=bold
syn match Asterisks contained "**" conceal                                      
syn match AsteriskBold "\*\*[^*]\+\*\*" contains=Asterisks
```